# Defining a range of IP in tshark

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a pcap file and I am trying to find out source IP's that lie within a certain range in this file.

I did the following:

```
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e ip.src ip.src >= 10.0.0.0 && ip.src <= 10.255.255.255
```

But this doesn't seem to work and gives the error `tshark: "10.0.0.0" was unexpected in this context.`
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by @jon-ander-ortiz-durántez is *basically* correct, according to the [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man page, there's actually nothing wrong, per se, with your original attempt, at least according to the current documentation:

`A capture or read filter can either be specified with the -f or -R option, respectively, in which case the entire filter expression must be specified as a single argument (which means that if it contains spaces, it must be quoted), or can be specified with command-line arguments after the option arguments, in which case all the arguments after the filter arguments are treated as a filter expression. If the filter is specified with command-line arguments after the option arguments, it's a capture filter if a capture is being done (i.e., if no -r option was specified) and a read filter if a capture file is being read (i.e., if a -r option was specified).`

The problem here is that there are bugs in the `tshark` documentation.  The filter at the end is **NOT** a ***read*** filter at all, but rather it's a ***display*** filter and it **MUST** be quoted to be reliable.  If you simply quote the filter, then it should work just fine:

```
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e ip.src "ip.src >= 10.0.0.0 && ip.src <= 10.255.255.255"
```

That said, in this particular case I'd use `"ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8"` because it's more terse, but I would also recommend *explicitly* using the syntax for display filters, namely `-Y <filter>`, so something like this:

```
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -Y "ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8"
```

Now, how can you tell it's a **display** filter and not a **read** filter?  It becomes more evident when you also include the frame number.  Both of these should produce the same output:

```
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e ip.src -Y "ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8"
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e ip.src "ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8"
```

However, this one will produce different results (assuming not every packet matches the filter)

```
tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e ip.src -2R "ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8"
```

Assuming not all packets match the filter, the output using the *read* filter will have sequential frame numbers whereas the output using the *display* filter will have non-sequential frame numbers that match the frame numbers of the original file instead of being renumbered like those of the *read* filter will have.

I would recommend filing a [Wireshark Bug Report](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues) regarding the problem with the `tshark` documentation with respect to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

IP Ranges on Wireshark are specified using CIDR blocks[1].

To define all possible IP addresses under  10.XX.XX.XX range just set:

`tshark -r myFile.pcap -T fields -e ip.src ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8`

[1] https://www.networkcomputing.com/networking/how-define-ip-range-wireshark